# @OneToMany unidirectional with unique elements

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I have two entities -

```
@Entity
class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
class TaskGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Task> tasks=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

As you can see the relation is unidirectional. What I want is -

- No join table
- Task on a TaskList should be unique.
- I want the mapped column to be created on TaskList table. Task table should not have any clue about the relation.

Can someone tell me how can achieve that?

I am using latest JPA with Hibernate.

Comment: I tried like this -
    `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="task_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();`

But this creates a task_id column on Task table.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that jpa can handle this without a join table.

Actually i think even if jpa could you should handle this behaviour in the objects.

You should override the equals and hashcode methods of Task and change the List to Set in the TaskGroup.

Or you can check the list in the TaskGroup's @PrePersist and @PreUpdate methods.